# how to check goodness-of-fit for linear mixed effects in spss

Tags: mixed-model, model, linear

I use linear mixed model (in SPSS) to analyze data (do not know if it is normal or not). After analysis, I get residual, then I check residual by P-P plot to see the goodness-of-fit of this model, is it right?

Comment: This is too brief to make a good question. As yet it does not allow much more than: Yes, it is certainly a good idea to use residuals to check whatever is assumed by whatever your model assumptions are. If you are fishing for SPSS code, that would usually be off-topic here.

Comment: but what is the tradition way to check goodness of fit for linear mixed effects in spss? or to see the "-2 Restricted Log Likelihood" to judge the goodness of fit? I am not clear about this. In other statistic model (general linear model etc.), I usually use p-p plot on residuals to see the goodness. Thanks!